# threejs/raycaster will not see the objects i need

Tags: three.js, raycasting

my raycaster is not seeing the objects it needs to see, i tried putting the mouse x y z on the cordinates the object is in and that still does not work, im new to three.js and raycasting so im stuck on this problem for the last 2 days

```
this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

this.mouse = new THREE.Vector3();

s.raycaster.setFromCamera(s.mouse, s.getCamera() );

s.canvas_model[0].addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(event) 
{s.onMouseDown(event);} , false); 

onMouseDown(event) {
    let s = this;
    s.bounds = s.canvas_model[0].getBoundingClientRect()
    s.mouse.x = ( (event.clientX - s.bounds.left) / s.canvas_model[0].clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    s.mouse.y = - ( (event.clientY - s.bounds.top) / s.canvas_model[0].clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    s.intersects = s.raycaster.intersectObjects(s.blocks, true);

    for ( var i = 0; i < s.intersects.length; i++){
        s.intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        console.log(s.intersects)
        console.log(s.mouse.x);
        console.log(s.mouse.y);

    } 
    if (s.intersects == 0){
        // console.log(s.intersects)
        // console.log(s.mouse.x)
        // console.log(s.mouse.y)
    }
```

i have tried s.scene.children it will see the floor and grid but not the blocks [screenshot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faNkI.png)

hope someone here has had a problem like this and can help me out here

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?

Comment: for some reason i cannot get it to work on jsfiddle i`m new to all of this

Comment: I think it's not possible to provide useful help just based on the information you have provided so far. A live example would make it much easier to analyze your problem.

Comment: i can upload the full folder to github if that can help you

Comment: @magen87 https://github.com/C4rdz/blokjes3d/blob/master/blokjes_3d/js/Blokjes3DCMS.js
https://github.com/C4rdz/blokjes3d/blob/master/blokjes_3d/cms_exercise.php

the part you need in the CMS is 856 and down

Comment: Thanks for sharing but the code is not helpful. Your issue needs debugging and that only works with a live example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/krLb5fx3/9/ this is what i got but i cannot get it to run the class and i cannot find out why